# Why is this css overriding this other one?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have 2 css files in my page:

1. Site.css
2. jquery-ui.css

Site.css is listed BELOW the jquery-ui css

I have a link that looks like this on my page:

```
 <a class='closeClueTipLink'>close</a>
```

and the issue is that the link is showing up black instead of the normal blue text.  When i use firebug to figure out why, i see this:

[image]

I don't understand why *.ui-widget-content* (which has the color #222222) is overriding *.closeClueTipLink* (which as color:blue) given that site.css is below the jquery one.

Any ideas or suggestions why this ordering is happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there's an `a` selector just after `.ui-widget-content`:

```
.ui-widget-content a
```

Making it more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) than `.closeClueTipLink`, even though `.closeClueTipLink` is found in a later stylesheet.

You could easily balance this out by adding the same type selector to your other rule so you get `a.closeClueTipLink`, making both selectors equally specific (1 type and 1 class). Then that, being the rule that's defined and loaded later, will apply and your link text will be blue.

Comment: I chose to answer the "why" first as that's the only thing being asked. Anyway I've worked in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Fix:**

Add an "a" before your class selector:

```
a.closeClueTipLink {
```

**Explanation:**

It has to do with [Specificity [details]](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).

The `.ui-widget-content a` is more "specific" because it references a class AND an element, as opposed to yours which just references a class.  Therefore, the `.ui-widget-content a` will override anything less specific regardless of location/placement of code.'

By adding an "a" before your selector, you make it ALSO reference an element and a class, therefore it's no longer less specific and will use location to determine.

Example:

```
/* css */
div p { color: red; }
p { color: blue; }

<!-- html -->
<div><p>Text</p></div>
```

The text in the above paragraph will be **red** because the first CSS item is more specific than the second.

Comment: Wrong. It should be "a.closeClueTip"

Comment: Fixed.  While typing, I was replicating the .ui-widget one, and forgot to look how it differed from his selector :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Because `.ui-content-content a { }` is loaded after the previous style `.closeClueTipLink`.</strike>

I am pretty sure `jquery...tom.css` is loaded after `site.css`, so the styles defined later overrides previously defined styles.

There are ways you are amend this problem:

1. Pinpoint the selector like `.ui-content-content a.closeClueTipLink`
2. Use `!important` at the end of color defination. `color: #222 !important;`<sup>*[not recommended]*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`.ui-widget-content a` is more specific than `.closeClueTipLink` so it will overide it no matter what order they are placed in.

change it to read

```
a.closeClueTipLink
```